# Why I cannot update the Account ID on this for loop?

Tags: salesforce-id, string, update, loop, for

```
for (Account acc : newAcc_lst) {
    System.debug('to15format Test 1-> ' + acc.id);
    Id to15convertString = acc.id;
    System.debug('to15format Test 2-> ' + to15convertString);
    String to15format = to15convertString.to15();
                
    System.debug('to15format Test 3-> ' + to15format);
    acc.id = to15format;
    System.debug('to15format Test 4-> ' + acc.id);
}
        
update newAcc_lst;
```

DEBUGS:

```
to15format Test 1-> 0017Y0000testedQAJ
to15format Test 2-> 0017Y0000testedQAJ
to15format Test 3-> 0017Y0000tested
to15format Test 4-> 0017Y0000testedQAJ
```

So, the Id cannot be updated to new 15 characters Id. Why is the reason?

Comment: 15 and 18 character IDs are entirely equivalent. 15 character variants are case sensitive, whilst the 18 character equivalents are case insensitive (so work even if you lowercase the ID content). Why are you trying to do what you're doing?

Comment: I suspect `System.debug` simply always outputs IDs in the 18 character format, but I've never specifically checked.

Comment: So, is not possible to that ID change from 18 to 15? This is part of method of TestClass, and I need it to testing functionality of external methods. In those external methods, code searches for ID 15 characters in MAP, and, if it does not find it, code fails... So, test fails because of it.

Comment: Since 15 and 18 are the same, I see no point in testing such conversion. I suggest you actually work with "Id" instances instead of Strings, since these will be agnostic of length.

Comment: Any on-platform code that fails to be agnostic between 15 and 18 character Ids is broken and needs to be fixed.

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). If you're having ID problems in Apex, you're doing something wrong. Always use the Id data type instead of String, and always use the 18-character ID values.

Comment: @CPS it should not matter if the ID field is 15 or 18 format, it's transparent for the developer, although it might be not transparent in a certain custom implementation (but for sure it's not the right design). Please provide a wider context i.e. what is the contract for those unit tests you mentioned, and I think we'll be able to help you then.